# war specific configuration file

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I would like to run different versions of my Grails (2.3.5) app at the same time in the same tomcat using different DBs.

At the moment I am having an external configuration file where I specify my DB configurations.

The filename is hardcoded:

```
  <tomcat-home>/conf/sc.conf
```

"sc.war" is the name of my war-file. As I now want/need to run multiple versions I would like to make the name of the conf file variable.

```
<tomcat-home>/conf/<warfilename>.conf
```

Is there a way to get the war-file-name at runtime?

I am open for other ways to solve my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give applicationBaseDir path into external config file

```
applicationBaseDir              =       ""
println "Bootstrapping application"
println ">>>>>>>>Environment >>>>>"+GrailsUtil.environment

Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
    development {
        println "Keeping applicationBaseDir "+grailsApplication.config.applicationBaseDir+" as is."
    }
    production {
//Following code finds your project path and set applicationBaseDir 
        Process findPresentWorkingDirectory = "pwd".execute()
        def pwd =  findPresentWorkingDirectory.text
        def pwdTokens = pwd.tokenize("/")
        pwdTokens.pop()
        applicationBaseDir = pwdTokens.join("/")
        println ">>>> applicationBaseDir "+applicationBaseDir
        applicationBaseDir = "/"+applicationBaseDir+"/webapps/applicationDir/"
        println 'grailsApplication.config.applicationBaseDir '+applicationBaseDir
    }
```

}

Or you directly set applicationBaseDir in external config file

```
applicationBaseDir = "/home/tomcat/webapps/applicationDir/"
```

Now, to refer specific external config file add into your project file Config.groovy file following code

```
environments {
   development {

    String codeSystemClassFilePath  = AnyDomainClassNameFromYourApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
// Here AnyDomainClassNameFromYourApplication change to your application domain class name e.g.I have domain class Student then I replace it with Student
    def arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName = codeSystemClassFilePath.split('/target/classes/')[0].split('/')
    String projectName                  = arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName[arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName.size()-1]
    println "App name in dev==>"+projectName


    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    grails.config.locations = [
            "file:${userHome}/grails/${projectName}.groovy"
    ]

    grails.assets.storagePath = ""
  }
  production {

    String codeSystemClassFilePath  = AnyDomainClassNameFromYourApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
    def arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName = codeSystemClassFilePath.split('/WEB-INF/classes/')[0].split('/')
    String projectName                  = arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName[arrayWithLastValueAsProjectName.size()-1]
    println "App name in production==>"+projectName

    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
    grails.config.locations = [
            "file:${userHome}/grails/${projectName}.groovy"
    ]
 }
}
//here grails/ is my default folder use to store exernal-config-files
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want my config file to be dependent on the war files name. Some examples:
abc.war -> <tomcat_home>/conf/config-abc.groovy or  
yxz.war  -> <tomcat_home>/conf/config-xyz.groovy

Comment: I edited the answer, so you can refer external config file from the application.

Comment: Thanks that Looks Good. Will try and let you know.